# Is there a way to set the SameSite cookie to none with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, cookies, samesite, lti

On an Apache test server, our vendors were able to achieve what we needed by setting

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None
```

in .htaccess. However, our live site is running Nginx and we are having trouble figuring out how to translate this into something we can configure there.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none";`